# Combined Jack headset (mic/audio) to audio only

Tags: cable, connector

I have a headset with an integrated microphone. It has only one jack cable but fortunatly came with a splitter (like this one [here](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcT0bZrB0pPg5jjUeADs3_hHBoXshgX7s0D5OcSTyCYwiGrnYpeU44qrAz94HKgC0gsGOVfx5x0H-A&usqp=CAc)) to have two 3.5mm jacks, one for the stereo audio going to the headset, and one for the mono mic signal out of the headset. I want to use it to monitor a 6.3 mm jack 1/4 inch stereo jack output from my mixer. Will leaving the mic (pink/red) cable unconnected lead to interferences. If so, what can I do to prevent them ? thanks

Comment: the splitter you are showing has two stereo jacks there - one for audio but the mic should be mono unless the signal is split to L/R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the mic jack isn't connected to anything on the other end it shouldn't present a problem. Just the same, I'd cover it with a piece of electric tape to avoid any confusion about which to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it without the adapter.  The usual convention these days for headsets with TRRS connector is to have "shield" as the mic signal and then ground and the two stereo signals in correspondence to where the contact wipers of a TRS socket are.  That tends to work "plug&play".  When S is actually ground (the way the socket has originally been designed) and the mic is on the second ring, connections tend to be sketchy since then the ground connection is established not by a contact wiper but by the socket bore.  In that case, your best bet is the adapter.  But I'd try without it first.  If you find you get reliable output, that will be by far the easiest solution.